# Counting the roots of $f(z)=z^4+z^3-2z^2+2z+4$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots

I have a polynomial $f(z)=z^4+z^3-2z^2+2z+4$, and I want to find the number of roots in the first quadrant. I'm trying to use the argument principle (or Rouche), and I could try to make my contour the quarter circle, but I've having trouble because I can't justify that there are no roots on the real axis. Please give me some recommendations!

So now I understand why there are no roots on the contour; I have also justified that the integral on the arc goes to $2\pi i$ by normal limit considerations. However, I still am unsure how to figure out the arguments.

Comment: $-1$ is a root so one can factor it

Comment: $z=-1$ is an obvious root. So factor out $(z+1)$ and then you get a cubic polynomial on which you can try Rouche's theorem.

Comment: @Conrad But I understand I could just figure out that $-1$ and $-2$ are roots and factor the remaining part, but I'd like to try to solve this explicitly with the theorems I mentioned above.

Comment: on the positive axis there are no roots because $z^4-2z^2+1 \ge 0$ and then you add to it only positive numbers when $z>0$

Comment: @Conrad I see, that makes sense... however afterwards I'm still struggling to understand what the change in argument would be.

Comment: why don't you pick a large $R$ (actually $R=3$ will do) and show that $f$ and $z^4+4$ have the same number of in the frst quadrant of the circle $|z|=R$; since $z^4+4$ has roots at $45,135,225,315$ degrees, there is only one in the first quadrant...

Comment: @Conrad Yes I could do that... Haha, would it simply be not workable to consider the argument directly?

Answer (score 4):

This one is a real weird one.

That is because I am tempted to factor this polynomial.

Let us try the rational root theorem first. If there is a rational root $\frac pq$ then $p$ divides $4$ and $q$ divides $1$ i.e. that root must be a multiple of $4$.

Merely trying out $z = -1$ works. Upon division by $z+1$ we get $z^3-2z+4$.

Another use of RRT gives $z = -2$ as a root, and division by $z+2$ yields $z^2-2z+2$, which by the usual quadratic formula is $(z-1+i)(z-1-i)$.

So, we have the roots as $1\pm i, -1,-2$. Of these, exactly the root $1+i$ is in the positive quadrant.

While this may be disappointing as an answer because we have not used machinery, it is suitable for a beginner. I would always suggest it as a first approach, and then look to apply Rouche or something else if things did not work out.

Comment: +1 for exposing me to the rational root theorem.

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Rouche method if you prove that there are no roots on the *positive* real axis, which is the part of the real axis that's on your path.

When $x>\sqrt2$ (I'm using $x$ here to emphasize we're dealing with a real variable in the proof), $x^4$ has a greater absolute value than $-2x^2$ and the latter is the only negative term, thus the polynomial is forced (strictly) positive.  Similarly, $4$ dominates $-2x^2$ for $0<x<\sqrt2$ and the sum $x^4+4$ dominates $-2x^2$ for the remaining case $x=\sqrt2$.

So there must be no positive real roots and you can use a Rouche path that includes the positive real axis.  You should, of course, compare your result with that obtained by elementary techniques from Aston.